# HorizontalScrollView disappeared when I lock screen on android 4.1

Tags: horizontalscrollview, lockscreen

My horizontalScrollView is shown noraml.now,I lock the screen,and then open it,the horizontalScrollView is disappeared.but on gingerbread it works well.what's the reason?anyone can help me?

here is the java code:

```
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.shop_bottom_tips, null);
    RelativeLayout shopLayout (RelativeLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.shop_tips_layout_id);
    AsyncImageView imageView = (AsyncImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.shop_tips_img_id);
    for(...) {
      //add child to the view.
   }
```

layout code:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/poster_shop_layout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```